# SQL query to return The last name of actor who has worked with each actor the most

Tags: mysql, sql, database, video

I am new to sql and im trying to write a query to return the last name of an actor who has worked with each actor the most.

I have 3 tables

```
Actor- id, first_name,last_name
Movie- id, title
Cast- pid, mid
```

This is what I got now but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT tt.ll
FROM Actor as AA ,Movie,Cast,(select a.id as idd, a.first_name,a.last_name as ll, count(*)
from Actor a
join Cast c on c.pid = a.id
where mid in (select mid from Cast where pid = AA.id) 
and pid <> AA.id 
group by a.id
order by count(*) desc, a.last_name ASC limit 1) tt
WHERE pid=AA.id AND Cast.mid=Movie.id 
group by AA.id;
```

Comment: IS the question correct -- I ask because your query looks at director a lot but the question does not include the director,movie_director tables

Comment: The question is correct. My previous query was returning extra informations. I edited that but still isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of times that pairs of actors work together with a self join on `cast` or a correlated subquery:

```
select c.aid, c2.aid, count(*)
from cast c join
     cast c2
     on c.mid = c2.mid   -- same movie
group by c.aid, c2.aid
```

To get the most for each actor in column one, use a window function:

```
select aa.*
from (select c.aid, c2.aid as aid_2, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by c.aid order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from cast c join
           cast c2
           on c.mid = c2.mid   -- same movie
      group by c.aid, c2.aid
     ) aa
where seqnum = 1;
```

Then to fill in the movies, you can use two `join`s to the `actors` table.  I'll let you construct that.

Comment: My sql version doesnt support 'partition by' and 'over'. Is there anyway to write it without them?